# Access data of an object using includes() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have these 2 functions:

```js
function getData(str) {
    if (str.includes("12/")) {
        return 'one';
    }

    if (str.includes("13/")) {
        return 'two';
    }
}

function getDataMapp(str) {
  const mapp = {
    '12/': 'one',
    '13/': 'two',
  };
  
  return mapp[str];
}
```

The function `getDataMapp` is the alternative of the first `getData` function. The issue of the second is that the first function uses `includes` checking not the strict mode, but in the second function i access object propriety strict like `mapp[str]`. In this way i don't get the expected behavior as in the first function. 
How to change the second function to get data using `includes()`?

Comment: @Bravo, i think you didn't read the question. I asked about changing the 2 function.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, could you show me the code example please?

Comment: What's wrong with the current "second" function? Why does it need to use `includes()`?

Comment: Loop over the keys/values and apply the same conditional logic you've already got?

Comment: `Object.entries(mapp).find(([k])=>str.includes(k))?.[1]` - the `?.` is in case nothing is found

Answer (score 0):

using `Object.entries`, and array `find`

```js
function getDataMapp(str) {
  const mapp = {
    '12/': 'one',
    '13/': 'two',
  };
  
  return Object.entries(mapp).find(([k])=>str.includes(k))?.[1];
}

console.log(getDataMapp('12/'))
console.log(getDataMapp('13/abc'))
console.log(getDataMapp('14/'))
```

or, without fancy ES6+ destructuring etc

```js
function getDataMapp(str) {
  const mapp = {
    '12/': 'one',
    '13/': 'two',
  };
  
  var result = Object.entries(mapp).find(function(x) {
    return str.includes(x[0]);
  });
  // if there is a result it'll be an array [key, value], so return value
  if (result) {
    return result[1];
  }
}

console.log(getDataMapp('12/'))
console.log(getDataMapp('13/abc'))
console.log(getDataMapp('14/'))
```